# How to call msbuild with wildcard on solution name (*.sln)?

Tags: command-line, msbuild

I have some solution files (*.sln) in a folder. How do I call `msbuild` for each of them without explicitly specify the solution name? The usual syntax is:

```
msbuild <solution-name>.sln /P:Configuration=<Debug,Release>
```

I tried this command but obviously it is not supported:

```
msbuild *.sln /P:Configuration=<Debug,Release>
```

Is there anyway to execute msbuild without knowing the solution name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate over the results of `dir *.sln` on the command line:

```
for %i in ( dir *.sln ) do ( msbuild %i /p:Configuration=Debug )
```

Or use an msbuild file to do the same. In the end this might be much more interesting as it allows more tweaking and automation. For instance the code shown below automatically builds both debug and release versions and can be extended for more. Also you can pass the directory to scan for solutions, and by default it picks the one where the msbuild file is. Such things are much harder and uglier on the command line or using batch files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- directory where the solution files are -->
    <SlnDir Condition="'$(SlnDir)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SlnDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- list solution files -->
    <ProjectFiles Include="$(SlnDir)\*.sln"/>
    <!-- list configurations to build -->
    <Configurations Include="Debug;Release"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFiles)" Targets="Cli" Properties="Configuration=%(Configurations.Identity)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: For my purposes removing ' Targets="Cli" ' from the MSBuild config line did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If using Powershell-Core then

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.sln | ForEach-Object $_ { msbuild $_ }
```